# Get the restaurant names that have rating count more than 50

Tags: python

I am trying to get the list of restaurants with a rating count

When I enter the following code:

```
# Filter the rated restaurants
df_rated = df[df['rating'] != 'Not given'].copy()

# Convert rating column from object to integer
df_rated['rating'] = df_rated['rating'].astype('int')  

# Create a dataframe that contains the restaurant names with their rating counts
df_rating_count = df_rated.groupby(['restaurant_name'])['rating'].count().sort_values(ascending = False).reset_index()
df_rating_count.head() 

# Get the restaurant names that have rating count more than 50
rest_names = df_rating_count[['rating']>50]['restaurant_name'] ## Complete the code to get the restaurant names having rating count more than 50
# Filter to get the data of restaurants that have rating count more than 50
df_mean_4 = df_rated[df_rated['restaurant_name'].isin(rest_names)].copy()

# Group the restaurant names with their ratings and find the mean rating of each restaurant
df_mean_4.groupby(['restaurant_name'])['rating'].mean().sort_values(ascending = False).reset_index().dropna() ## Complete the code to find the mean rating
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-9676daed1fbc> in <module>
      1 # Get the restaurant names that have rating count more than 50
----> 2 rest_names = df_rating_count[['rating']>50]['restaurant_name'] ## Complete the code to get the restaurant names having rating count more than 50
      3 # Filter to get the data of restaurants that have rating count more than 50
      4 df_mean_4 = df_rated[df_rated['restaurant_name'].isin(rest_names)].copy()
      5 

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

I am struggling to find a function that gets me the restaurants rated more than 50 times. <> Does not seem to work for int types.

Comment: Provide an example of a dataset so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your error seems to be in the line:

```
rest_names = df_rating_count[['rating']>50]['restaurant_name']
```

python treats `['rating']>50` as you comparing a list (instead of a series) to an integer (`50`).
Try changing this to:

```
rest_names = df_rating_count[df_rating_count['rating']>50]['restaurant_name']
```